# Android application of recognizing commands

Tags: react-native

[image: Output of app]

Can somebody tell me how to store keywords in AsynStorage react native? like if I command android "open notes" in sindhi language (khol notes) so directly notes will be displayed. If I ask what is time now? so directly time will be displayed. These commands will be in Sindhi language in android phone. Can somebody tell me it's coding? I have done it's coding & it shows it in text.

Comment: I corrected screenshot image display

Comment: thanks.. Can you please help me in this issue?